# how to add a onclick(onchange) event for a wicket radiobutton?

Tags: onclick, radio-button, wicket, onchange, radio-group

how to add a onclick(onchange) event for a wicket radiobutton?

Likes add a onclick() for button:

```
add(new Button("search") {
            @Override
            public void onSubmit() {
    ……
  }
```

I try it with below way, but can’t work:

```
Radio<String> radio = new Radio<String>("aaa", new Model<String>("AAA") {
          @Override
            public void onClick() {
            ……
          }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to do something on server side when onchange is fired, maybe the best solution is to add a AjaxEventBehavior to your radio buttons:

```
radioGroup.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("change") {
  protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
      System.out.println("ajax here!");
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Wicket `radio` button doesn't have `onclick` override method . So the best way it could be

```
Radio<String> radio  = new Radio<String>("aaa", new Model<String>("AAA"));
        radio.add(new AjaxFormSubmitBehavior("click") {
            @Override
            protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                //Your action whatever you want to do
            }
        });
```

Note: This radio should have form around it.And add this to radio group .

Comment: Thanks soorapadman, too. I have a form this time, but I will try it next time.